# Mi app se reinicia al llamar dos veces al método insert() de greendao

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, greendao

Tengo una app en la que quiero registrar en una base de datos cada inicio de sesión (tanto fallidos como correctos) y el primer intento sí lo registra bien pero al hacer un segundo intento, la app se cierra. He comprobado que se debe al método: sesionDao.insert(sesion). La conexión a la base de datos se la paso desde el activity a través del constructor.

```
public class BotonIniciarSesion  implements View.OnClickListener{
    Context contexto;
    EditText email;
    EditText pass;
    String emailString;
    String passString;
    Activity actividad;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    DaoSession ds;
    AccessDao ad;
    Access access=new Access();
    Date ahora;

    public BotonIniciarSesion(Context contexto, Activity actividad, EditText email, EditText pass,
                              SharedPreferences.Editor editor, AccessDao ad, Access access,DaoSession ds){
        this.contexto=contexto;
        this.email=email;
        this.pass=pass;
        this.actividad=actividad;
        this.editor=editor;
        this.ad=ad;
        this.ds=ds;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        emailString=email.getText().toString();
        passString=pass.getText().toString();
        access.setEmail(emailString);
        ahora=new Date();
        access.setCreated_at(ahora);

        if(passString.equals("dscr")){
            access.setValid(true);
            ad.insert(access);
            editor.putString("email", emailString);
            editor.commit();

            Toast toast1=Toast.makeText(this.contexto,"Bienvenido "+emailString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            actividad.finish();
        } else{
            access.setValid(true);
            ad.insert(access);
            Toast toast2=Toast.makeText(this.contexto,"Contraseña incorrecta",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
        }
    }
}
```

El mensaje que resulta del logcat es el siguiente:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.practica_3, PID: 15434
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: ACCESS._id (code 1555)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:780)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao.insertInsideTx(AbstractDao.java:368)
        at org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao.executeInsert(AbstractDao.java:351)
        at org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao.insert(AbstractDao.java:319)
        at com.example.practica_3.BotonIniciarSesion.onClick(BotonIniciarSesion.java:64)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Hola @satrus, Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español! Para que puedas encontrar ayuda, te recomiendo detallar un poco mas la pregunta, tal vez añadiendo una parte del código, explicando el contexto y/o el entorno de ejecución. Saludos

Comment: Las causas pueden ser diversas, ¿que se muestra en el LogCat? @Satrus

Comment: Añado el mensaje de error en la publicación

Comment: Al parecer tienes problemas en la consulta, no estas pasando los parámetro correctamente, o la configuración de tu tabla no te deja insertar elementos repetidos , tendrías que mostrarnos mas. Creo que lo que has posteado es donde no ocurre el error exacto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido resolver el error, resulta que la declaración del objeto Access access=new Access() debía hacerse dentro del método onclick() y no fuera, desconozco por qué.